# Recurrence Relation: $a_{n+2}+a_n=5\cos (n\pi/3)-7\sin(n\pi/4)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Recurrence Relation: $a_{n+2}+a_n=5\cos \left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)-7\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)$

**Attempt:**

The solution of the associated homogeneous relation is
\begin{align}
a_n^{(h)}&=c_1\left(\cos \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)+c_2\left(\cos \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-i\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)\\ &=k_1\cos \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)+k_2\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align}
where $k_1=c_1+c_2$ and $k_2=(c_1-c_2)i$

then
\begin{align*}
a_n^{(p)} = A\cos \left( \frac{n\pi}{3} \right)+B\sin \left( \frac{n\pi}{3} \right) +C \cos \left( \frac{n\pi}{4} \right)+D\sin \left( \frac{n\pi}{4} \right)
\end{align*}
is the particular solution. The four constants $A, B, C, D$ can be calculated by substituting $a_n^{(p)}$ in the given non-homogeneous recurrence relation. But I find it difficult to calculate.

Comment: You **can't** solve a recurrence like this without knowing two values, say $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: @user247327 Well, I do not get the initial values. I guess we can propose them.

Comment: Yes, lets assume we know $a_0$ and  $a_1$.

Oh, I forgot, we also need to assume two additional constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ 

in order to get a complete solution. (complementary function + particular 

solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with a way to express the general solution:

$$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
a_1\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
a_{22}\\
a_{23}\\
a_{24}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\underbrace{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}5\\
-1\\
a-5\\
-8.5\\
-2.5\\
6\\
7-a\\
6\\
-2.5\\
-8.5\\
a-5\\
-1\\
5\\
6\\
-a\\
-1.5\\
-2.5\\
-1\\
a+2.5\\
-1\\
-2.5\\
-1.5\\
-a\\
6\end{smallmatrix}\right)}_S+\alpha \underbrace{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\end{smallmatrix}\right)}_{K_1}+\beta \underbrace{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
-1\\
0\end{smallmatrix}\right)}_{K_2} \tag{*}$$

with $a:=f(1)=\frac{5-7 \sqrt{2}}{2}\approx 2.4497$, for any  $\alpha, \beta$.

Why considering 24 entries ? Because, for any $n$:

$$\sum_{k=n}^{k=n+23} f(k) = 0 \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \  f(k):=5\cos \left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)-7\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{4}\right)$$

(This could have been foreseen: $24$ is the shortest period for a cycle accomodating $\pi/3$ and $\pi/4$ like the Meton cycle for the Sun and the Moon...)

(See graphics below : the blue curve for function $f$ and the red curve for its cumulative values displaying the 24-periodicity),

[image]

As a consequence, we have the homogeneous recurrence relationship: $$a_{n+23}+a_{n+22}+2\left(\sum_{k=n+2}^{k=n+21} a_{k}\right)+a_{n+1}+a_n=0.$$

Let us stop here for a while. We know that the set of sequences $(b_n)$ (I voluntarily take a different notation) verifying relationship:

$$b_{n+23}+b_{n+22}+2\left(\sum_{k=n+2}^{k=n+21} b_{k}\right)+b_{n+1}+b_n=0.\tag{*}$$

is a vector space $V$ with dimension $24$. The set of sequences $a_n$ is therefore a subset (in fact an affine subspace) of $V$, with many constraints, all of them contributing to a final very low "dimensionality" of the issue.

Let us now switch to matrix algebra explanations.

Consider the $n= 24$ first linear relationships with a periodic indexing, meaning that $a_{25}=a_1, a_{26}=a_2$). This system of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns

$$\underbrace{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&1&0&0\cdots0&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\cdots0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\cdots0&0&0\\
&.&.&.&.&.&\\
&.&.&.&.&.&\\
&.&.&.&.&.&\\
0&0&0&0&0\cdots1&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&0\cdots0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\cdots0&0&1\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)}_A\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
a_n\\
a_{n+1}\\
a_{n+2}\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
a_{n+21}\\
a_{n+22}\\
a_{n+23}\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
f(n)\\
f(n+1)\\
f(n+2)\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
f(n+21)\\
f(n+22)\\
f(n+23)\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)\tag{2}$$

is not solvable because $A$ has rank $22$.

Indeed, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is:

$$[x(x - 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2)(x^2 - 3x + 3)(x^2 - x + 1)(x^4 - 4x^3 + 5x^2 - 2x + 1)]^2$$

We can place the finger where the issue is: $A$ having $0$ as a double value, has a kernel with dimension $2$, meaning that there are in fact two arbitrary constants, which isn't surprizing... We must assign arbitrary values to $a_1$ and $a_2$ to get a solution $S$.

A basis of the kernel are the vectors $K_1, \ K_2$ with resp. entries $\cos k\pi/2$ and $\sin k\pi/2$, $\ k=1... 24$ (see formula (*).

---

Remark: I had investigated the 24 dimensional
space of sequences. Here are some interesting facts, but in fact not at all useful for the solution of this problem.

The characteristic equation of (*) is

$$r^{22}(r+1)+2(\sum_{k=2}^{21} r^k)+(r+1)=0 \tag{1}$$

(which has the property to be reciprocal) has the following 23 distinct roots (obtained using a Computer Algebra System):

$$-1, \pm i, \pm w^k, k=1,2,...10 \ \ \text{where} \ w=e^{i \pi/11}$$

As a consequence, the general expression is:

$$a_n=K(-1)^n+L(i^n)+M(-i)^n+\sum_{k=1}^{10} C_k e^{ik \pi/11}+\sum_{k=1}^{10} D_k e^{-ik \pi/11}$$

for certain constants $K,L,M,C_k,D_k$ ($k=1:10$).

Due to the fact that the sequence $a_n$ is a real sequence i.e., such that $a_n=\overline{a_n}$, we can conclude that $L=M$ and for all $k$, $C_k=D_k$.

It remains to find unknowns $K,L,C_1,C_2,... C_{10}$ by setting the different constraints, which would lead to another much more complicated way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is our road map:

First we find a particular solution $p_n$, then a complementary solution $f_n$. Set

$a_n = f_n + p_n $, we are done.

---

It is easy to find a particular solution $p_n$.

For example, set $a_0$ = 0, $a_1$= 1 we get, for n = 2, 3, 4

[image: Generate sequence <span class=]$p_n$" />

To find the complete solution, we find the complementary function

$f_n$ from the solution of

$x^2$ + 1 = 0.

Its solutions are x= -i or i.

Thus we have $f_n$ = $C_1$ cos nπ/2 + $C_2$sin nπ/2

and $a_n$ = $f_n$ + $p_n$ = $C_1 cos nπ/2 + C_2 sin nπ/2 + p_n$

Comment: $x^2+1=0$ has solutions $x=\pm i$...

Comment: My bad, I made some trivial errors.  @Jean Thanks  for pointing out my mistakes.